# On what basis does the Finder update the file copy progression bar?

Tags: mac, file-transfer

I want to know that the progression of the progress bar in OS X is based on which factors by the Finder?

- Time (passing or estimated)
- Number of files remaining
- Size of files remaining

If possible, can we change the factor used in any way to match our choice?

[image: finder copy window]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make a somewhat educated guess

- The bar shows "time spent" vs. "overall time expected"
- "overall time expected" is somewhat dynamic, depending on current throughput. So if you start of with a lot of small files (which usually take longer than a large one) transfer seems to speed up later (and vice versa)
- I'm not aware of any way to change this

PS: And no, I don't have a reference for that, just years of observation

Answer (score 0):

How a progress bar operates is completely up to the developer who wrote that portion of the application. If he/she has put no provisions in any preferences to allow a user to adjust or modify it then it can't be done. The class name in Cocoa is NSProgressIndicator, and the methods setMaxValue and setMinValue set the extremes of the bar, and it's up to the developer to increment the progress bar when it needs updating.

You MIGHT be able to adjust it if there's a setting for it, but usually not.

Hope this helps.